# JFace/SWT Selection Event Programatically - Tree

Tags: java, treeview, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Would like to trigger a Tree selectionChanged event automatically through code for an Eclipse RCP application.
Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a JFace TreeViewer you could get the selection, set it to `null` and then set the old selection back. Like this:

```
TreeSelection oldSelection = new TreeSelection((TreeSelection)treeViewer.getSelection().getPaths());
treeViewer.setSelection(null);
treeViewer.setSelection(oldSelection);
```

Comment: Tried both the solutions and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `TreeViewer`, you can use this to select an item programmatically:

```
viewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(viewer.getElementAt(position)), true);
```

If you are using a `Tree`, use this:

```
tree.setSelection(tree.getItem(position));
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, for others who wish to set the selected tree node, based on an object from your own node model - you can do it this way:

```
IStructuredSelection selection = new StructuredSelection(yourObjectFromModel);
tree.setSelection(selection, true);
```

Thanks to [Lauri](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t33899.html#91887960) for that one.